# Save or send back emails based on keyword

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I have managed to write a script in Outlook VBA which does the following:
- scan every incoming email in a specific inbox folder
- detect whether a certain keyword (an ID based on "R", the name of the Year, either a "/", a "-" or some other  and an incrementing number, p.e. R16/000001)
- if there is the keyword: save the email and attachements to a certain folder
- if not: send the mail back, asking for the keyword

Now, this works totally fine, just some mails I receive get sent back even though the keyword is there and totally correct.
The keyword can be anywhere in the subject, the subject can be anything. So I tried changing the subject from the specific emails that get sent back, but it didn't work. Here's my code, but I'm not quite sure this is a coding problem.

Find position of the keyword *UPDATED*:

```
Dim i As Integer
reklPos = 0
For i = 10 To 20
    If InStr(UCase(txt), "R" & i) Then
        reklPos = InStr(UCase(txt), "R" & i)
    End If
Next i
```

Check if keyword is correct:

```
If reklPos = 0 Then
    isReklNr = 0
ElseIf Not isNaN(Mid(txt, reklPos + 3, 1)) Then
    isReklNr = 9
Else
    isReklNr = 10
End If
```

isNaN Function:

```
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To Len(txt)
    If Mid(txt, i, 1) Like "[0-9]" Then
        isNaN = False
    Else
        isNaN = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next i
```

Based on this, if isReklNr returns 0, an email will be sent back. I'd appreciate any idea why this is not working only on some emails. Thank you!

** Update **

Some examples where the code failed:

- "VIV 14198 OPPERVLAKTEFOUTEN R16/005367",
- "VIV13966 R16/004062",
- "VIV13702 R16/002182 - 1,4 t "

And some that passed:

- "R16/005370_200189671_SCB",
- "AW: R16/005301_Todoaceros",
- "WG: Per E-Mail senden: VR 003108.pdf - Rekl. Wälzholz/Wickede - R16/005328",
- "WG: Aktuelle Qualitätsbeanstandung - IB 200006250 - R16/005332"

** UPDATE 2 **
Some subjects that contain only the keyword also get sent back. When I write a new mail with the same subject, it passes and gets correctly saved.

Comment: Can you include a few subject lines that passed the check and a few that (incorrectly) failed?

Comment: of course, i will!

Answer (score 0):

I have tried linking your code snippets together but cannot get them to work.  I list some errors below but this is more a description of how I would develop a routine like this.

Although you need this routine for an Outlook macro, this routine could be used within Excel or Access or any other Office product.  It seems to me that the Excel-VBA site is used more heavily than the Outlook-VBA site.  Certainly, there are more Excel questions than Outlook questions and good Excel questions are answered more quickly than good Outlook questions.  Even without this opinion of Stack Overflow, I would develop this macro in Excel.

I have created a workbook “Develop isReklNr.xlsm” to which I copied your code and attempted, unsuccessfully, to convert it to a set of working routines.  I have created a test harness and a dummy check function to replace yours so I can demonstrate my approach.

I have created a worksheet named TestData which contains:

[image]

In column A, I have placed your sample values.  I would add faulty values – some subtly wrong some totally wrong – so I could thoroughly exercise the check routine.  In column C, I have entered “A” against the correct sample values and would enter “R” against faulty values.  My test harness calls the check routine for every value in column A and writes the result to column B.  In column D, I have entered formulae to compare the check function’s result against my expected value.  The value “Different” in column D tells me that there are bugs in the check routine.

Having developed the check routine, I would copy it to Outlook and archive the workbook.  If later a bug was found or if the format of the reference number changed, I would retrieve the workbook.  I would add new values to worksheet TestData and correct/update the check routine as necessary.  Column D would tell me if I my correction/update was error free.  It would also confirm that I had not introduced a bug that meant other values were no longer accepted or rejected correctly.  If I had problems I would post my complete code (not snippets) on the Excel-VBA site and expect to get a speedy reply.

I hope I have explained my approach well enough for you to understand its advantages.

My test harness is:

```
Option Explicit
  Const ColTestStr As Long = 1
  Const ColAccRej As Long = 2
Sub Test()

  Dim RowCrnt As Long
  Dim RowLast As Long

  With Worksheets("TestData")
    RowLast = .Cells(Rows.Count, ColTestStr).End(xlUp).Row

    For RowCrnt = 3 To RowLast
      If Check(.Cells(RowCrnt, ColTestStr).Value) Then
        .Cells(RowCrnt, ColAccRej).Value = "A"
      Else
        .Cells(RowCrnt, ColAccRej).Value = "R"
      End If
    Next

  End With

End Sub
Function Check(ByVal Txt As String) As Boolean

  Check = True

End Function
```

`Check` is my dummy check routine.  As I said, I cannot get yours to work.

**My assessment of your code**

I assume the first two blocks of code form Boolean function `isReklNr`.  The trouble with assumption is that `isReklNr` is set to 0, 9 or 10.  These values make no sense to me.

In `Dim i As Integer`, please replace `Integer` with `Long`.  With VBA, `Integer` declares a 16-bit integer value.  This requires special processing on a 32 or 64-bit computer.  `Long` declares a 32-bit value which is more appropriate.

In the For-Loop, you should have `Exit For` within the If statement so it exits when a good value is found.

In your text you say the reference number starts “Rnn” where “nn” is a year.  You are checking for "R0", "R1", "R2" or "R3".  I would check that the two characters after “R” are numeric and, if they are, that they are within an appropriate range.

Your `isNaN` function checks a multi-character string to be all decimal digits.  However, it is only called with one character which is X in “RnnX”.  But “X” is “/” or “-” so `isNaN` always returns False.